# MVC razor debug and release

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developping an application in MVC 4 (.Net 4.5.2) using Visual Studio 2012. My application is to fill forms and save it into SQL database

What's happen is when I test on Localhost I don't have any error but when I publish on the server from time to time I have error message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 1.
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

it's been many days and I am not able to find what's going one, Sometimes I have this error and sometimes not, I am not able to see where is the problem, Any help please??

> [HttpCompileException]: External component has thrown an exception.
>   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.CreateInstanceOfType[T](String
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance[T](IVirtualPathFactory
>   factory, String virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.CreateInstanceOfType[T](String
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryExtensions.CreateInstance[T](IVirtualPathFactory
>   factory, String virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.CreatePageFromVirtualPath(String
>   virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists,
>   DisplayModeProvider displayModeProvider, IDisplayMode displayMode)
>   at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__2(TextWriter
>   writer)    at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter
>   writer)    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult
>   result)    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action 1 body)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList
>   1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList
>   1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList 1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult
>   1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase 1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid
>   1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase 1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid
>   1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase 1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid
>   1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase 1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: does iis have .net 4.5 installed? is your appPool pointing to 4.x ?

Comment: I am with Arvixe they have .NET 4.5 http://www.arvixe.com/asp_net_45_hosting and as the technical support told me that even if I choose .net 4.0, 4.5 is supported

Comment: Which version of windows server are you using? Which version of IIS are you using? .Net 4.5 will be running with .net 4.0 in the IIS config. However, check if the application pool is configured as Integrated and the Identity provider is Network Service. I found some issues and they stop when I setup the server with these properties. Using Windows Server 2012. Check also this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017839/compilation-error-after-successful-publish-of-asp-net4-0-web-application Because part of you log is pointing to errors in IIS configuration.