# How can I get code of aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a VS 2005 web site that I publish using "Publish Web Site", and I clear all the three checkboxes.I decomplile mypage.aspx.989dc2fb.compiled file by using .NET reflector 8.2.0 then I can't find mypage.aspx UI code and javascript code.How can I find those contents.Please help me.

Comment: This is also nice to check out when you are decompiling http://ilspy.net/

Answer (score 1):

Check out your publishing settings. Usually assemblies shouldn't include javascript or .aspx, so they must be in a raw form. Look for option "Allow precompiled site to be updatable".

Comment: Thanks for the response.Moreover,I face another problem.I modified mypage.aspx file and publish web site.Then, I replace that file with the old one.The file '/mypage.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested error appear.How can I replace that file?

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602117/how-to-fix-asp-net-error-the-file-nnn-aspx-has-not-been-pre-compiled-and-can). Try to set fixed naming in your publishing settings or put the correct assembly path in the .aspx file (in the "inherits" parameter of the first tag).

Comment: Yes,thank u very much Mr.Baseleus.I checked 'fixed naming and single page assemblies' and published website.Then,I replaced .compiled and assembly files of mypage.aspx in bin folder .But , I get that error agian.Please help me what should I do.

Comment: So try to precompile your website during publishing. Also I recommend  to use the option "delete all existing files prior to publish" because after a few publishes you could get a lot of useless garbage in your website directory.