# "The file was not precompiled and could not be requested" all of a sudden

Tags: iis, webforms

We are running several WebForms-Application on a Web Hoster (classic IIS, no Azure, no Docker, etc). For some months now, ca. once a month, one or more of these (virtual) applications stop working all of a sudden. In the Application Log Files there is an HttpException: "The file ....aspx was not precompiled and could not be requested." After redeploying (republishing) the application everything is working fine until next month. The Hoster did not find anything inside his log files.

What could be the problem? Where to start search?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you used Release Mode, it is always recommended that you publish website in Release Mode

Comment: Yes, it is Release Mode. But what would be the difference?

Comment: Debug includes debug information in the compiled files while Release usually has optimizations enabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602117/how-to-fix-asp-net-error-the-file-nnn-aspx-has-not-been-pre-compiled-and-can

Comment: I hope that helps you