# View engine failing after application runs for a while

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC 5 framework that runs a bunch of sites and we have an issue where as the site runs for a few days(sometimes even hours), it begins to error about being able to load views (The partial view `~/Views/Comment/ExtraHeaders.ascx` was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations the following locations were searched).

The error also occasionally says "The file '/Views/Cobalt/Shared/Error.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested" This view file is also definitely there

We do precompile the views before deploying. This error persists after an app restart, but goes away when redeploying the code. Any ideas about how to debug the underlying problem?

I am going to try and do a byte by byte comparison of every file the next time it happens to see if maybe some corruption is happening?

Comment: please check `ExtraHeaders.ascx` is there under views-> Comment folder.

Comment: yeah the files are all there, the site will run for several days with no issues. The error happens about any view, suggesting it cant load the precompiled views at all

Comment: Please check this post :https://stackoverflow.com/a/602209/3829595

Comment: ive checked that post, but i wasnt able to find any good solutions for determining which assembly is causing the issue. I had assumed the issue was some invalid assembly, but im not sure how to tell which one is the issue or how to keep the site from getting in this situation in the first place